network error on lilygo t-echo
I am trying to flash the t-echo and had to use meshtastic's app in order to enable the serial port. However, now when I try to use flash.meshtastic.org it fails, here are the logs:
Chooser dialog is not displaying a port blocked by the Serial blocklist: bluetoothServiceClassId=0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, name='Outlier Free Pro'
flash.meshtastic.org/:1 Chooser dialog is not displaying a port blocked by the Serial blocklist: bluetoothServiceClassId=0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, name='Outlier Free Pro'
flash.meshtastic.org/:1 Chooser dialog is not displaying a port blocked by the Serial blocklist: bluetoothServiceClassId=0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, name='Outlier Free Pro'
flash.meshtastic.org/:1 Chooser dialog is not displaying a port blocked by the Serial blocklist: bluetoothServiceClassId=0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, name='Outlier Free Pro'
flash.meshtastic.org/:1 Chooser dialog is not displaying a port blocked by the Serial blocklist: bluetoothServiceClassId=00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, name='Outlier Free Pro'
flash.meshtastic.org/:1 Chooser dialog is not displaying a port blocked by the Serial blocklist: bluetoothServiceClassId=0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, name='Outlier Free Pro'
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:044 DEBUG   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  Constructor  SerialConnection instantiated
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:046 DEBUG   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  Configure ⚙️ Requesting device configuration
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:255 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node info for this device
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:256 DEBUG   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  GetMetadata ️ Received metadata packet
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:257 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 1124796501
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:268 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 2732916580
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:269 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 2086286252
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:269 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 4221273630
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:269 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 380337803
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:270 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 951955997
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:270 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 991551690
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:270 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 1136059212
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:270 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 3778153872
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:272 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 2733365860
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:272 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Node Info packet for node: 4092103587
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:274 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 0
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:274 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 1
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:275 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 2
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:275 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 3
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:276 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 4
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:277 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 5
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:277 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 6
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:278 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Channel: 7
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:279 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Config packet of variant: device
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:279 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Config packet of variant: position
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:280 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Config packet of variant: power
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:281 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Config packet of variant: network
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:282 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Config packet of variant: display
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:282 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Config packet of variant: lora
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:283 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Config packet of variant: bluetooth
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:284 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: mqtt
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:284 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: serial
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:285 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: externalNotification
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:286 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: storeForward
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:287 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: rangeTest
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:287 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: telemetry
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:288 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: cannedMessage
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:289 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: audio
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:289 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: remoteHardware
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:290 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: neighborInfo
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:291 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: ambientLighting
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:291 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: detectionSensor
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:292 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Module Config packet of variant: paxcounter
D-GSYMBb.js:57 Attempting to enter DFU mode
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:292 DEBUG   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  EnterDfuMode  Entering DFU mode
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:293 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  SendPacket  Sending ADMIN_APP to self
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:293 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio ⚙️ Valid config id received from device: 345652327
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:500 TRACE   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  HandleFromRadio  Received Queue Status: [object Object]
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:503 DEBUG   [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  ReadFromRadio Releasing reader
flash.meshtastic.org/:1 Uncaught (in promise) NetworkError: The device has been lost.Understand this errorAI
D-GSYMBb.js:45 22:23:15:505 INFO    [iMeshDevice:SerialConnection]  Connect Device disconnected

